# Is there a way to get tcp retransmit count PER PORT/SOCKET?

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux-networking, tcp

We hit an issue with one of our Kafka brokers (running over AWS EC2) suffering from many TCP retransmits.

We'd like to know which of the TCP connections it has open suffers from this.

Is there a way to break down the total count of TCP retransmits by socket, port or host (short of `tcpdump`)?

So far, I haven't found anything in the Linux docs or under `/proc`, or any external tools which provide this info.